# How to remove the min date from same table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have some simple records below.

```
CREATE TABLE TEMPS
(
    ID INT,
    ENTRY_DT DATETIME,
    BIRTH_DT DATETIME,
    NAMES VARCHAR (25)
)

INSERT INTO TEMPS 
VALUES ('123', '6/10/2015', '2/6/2018', 'JOHN'),
       ('123', '2/4/2018', '2/6/2018', 'SMITH'),
       ('123', '2/4/2018', '2/6/2018', 'DOE')
```

It returns

```
ID  Entry_Date  Birth_Date  Name
-----------------------------------
123 6/10/2015   2/6/2018    John
123 2/4/2018    2/6/2018    Smith
123 2/4/2018    2/6/2018    Doe
```

I am trying to find the records where the date or dates from the Entry_Date column that were closer (within 3-6 month ranges) from the Birth_Date column. For example in this TEMPs table, there are 2 records with entry date 2/4/18 that was close to birth date 2/6/18. Here is what i tried with two steps:

Step 1:

```
SELECT
    id, 
    MIN(entry_dt) AS entry_dt
INTO
    test
FROM
    temps
GROUP BY 
    id
```

Step 2:

```
SELECT * 
FROM temps a 
INNER JOIN test b ON a.id = b.id
WHERE a.entry_dt > b.entry_dt
```

What would be a more efficient way to pull more records than the temp table and what is the best method to filter out the records that fall within 3-6 months to the birth date?

Comment: Is 6/10/2015 the 6th Oct or 10th June?

Comment: I do not see you removing anything here, just selecting.  Please clarify your question with the expected results.  What do you mean by "pull more records than the temp table" here?

Comment: Hi Joe. Would you please refrain from signing your posts? I think I have made this edit before on your material. We do not sign posts here - the profile card is considered to be more than sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use insert data into test `table`. you can add condition in `where` clause.

```
where birth_dt between entry_dt and dateadd(month,3,entry_dt)
```

**Query**

```
select * 
from TEMPS
where birth_dt between entry_dt and dateadd(month,3,entry_dt)
```

**Output**
[image]